# How to get a oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection from an oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

Since ConnectionCaching ist deprecated in ojdbc now, i would like to use the Oracle [Universal Connection Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/toc.htm).

The Problem here is that i need to to obtain a oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection from it. I tried casting and unwrapping but i does not work. How do i get one?

I need the OracleConnection.createARRAY() Method to call a stored Procedure.

Comment: From UCP, you will get java.sql.Connection only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @6ton. I made it like this:

```
/* missing all error handling and resource management*/
universalConnectionPoolManager = UniversalConnectionPoolManagerImpl.getUniversalConnectionPoolManager();
poolDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
    // setting up dataSource .... 
poolDataSource.setConnectionPoolName(NAME);
universalConnectionPoolManager.createConnectionPool((UniversalConnectionPoolAdapter) poolDataSource);
universalConnectionPoolManager.startConnectionPool(NAME);
universalConnectionPool = universalConnectionPoolManager.getConnectionPool(NAME);
universalPooledConnection = universalConnectionPool.borrowConnection(universalConnectionPool.getConnectionRetrievalInfo());
physicalConnection = universalPooledConnection.getPhysicalConnection();
oracleConn = (OracleConnection) physicalConnection;
    // ... query stuff
universalPooledConnection.heartbeat();
universalConnectionPool.returnConnection(universalPooledConnection);
universalConnectionPoolManager.destroyConnectionPool(NAME);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the api docs, if you are getting an instance of [UniversalPooledConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12826/oracle/ucp/UniversalPooledConnection.html) the underlying connection can be obtained from getPhysicalConnection:

> getPhysicalConnection
>
> java.lang.Object getPhysicalConnection()
>
> Gets the physical connection
>   that this UniversalPooledConnection decorates.
>
> Returns: The physical
>   connection. Never null.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the OracleConnection by using the unwrap method as shown below.

```
PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();    
pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservice)))");        
pds.setUser("hr");        
pds.setPassword("hr");
pds.setConnectionPoolName("JDBC_UCP_POOL");
pds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
pds.setMinPoolSize(5);
pds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
try (Connection conn = pds.getConnection()) {          
   OracleConnection oc = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);          
} catch (SQLException e) {          
  System.out.println("UCPSample - SQLException occurred : " + e.getMessage());        
}
```

Comment: Like I said I already tried unwrapping. There was something like not-a-wrapper exception. The Connection you get back is some kind of com.sun.proxy class.